# How to get user domainpath Name using Netusergetinfo() in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Anyone know how to get user domainpath using [`NetUserGetInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function using c++?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @ Pileborg :using LPUSER_INFO_1 to 2,3 etc...i cant get,actually i dont know,which one has the user domainpath value.

Comment: @SanjuMonu what do you mean under "user domainpath"? can you clarify it or perhaps show an example of "user domainpath"?

Comment: @ Apokal :the path look like this, `OU=Marketing,DC=raja,DC=CO,DC=IN"` or `"CN=USERS,DC=raja,DC=COM"`